# VBA - How to decrypt PDF files using PDFTK.exe

Tags: pdf, encryption, pdftk

I have 2PDF files when i try to decrypt thes files i get OWNER PASSWORD ERROR

there is no owner password set in the file.
my Code

```
  set inputfile=%1
set outputfile=C:\Users\2512\Desktop\Rename\decrypt.pdf
set password=radhish
::set ownerpassword=
::pdftk %1 input_pw %2 output %3
pdftk %1  input_pw %password% output %outputfile% 
::echo HELLO %1! %2! %3! %4!
pause
```

Comment: What’s the VBA connection here?

Comment: *"there is no owner password"* - most likely there is. It or the user password might be the default password, though, so you do not need to enter any password to view the file.

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA (or programming at all)?

Comment: @TIM & ken White-I have this code in batch  file & i have triggered this batch file from shell command in vba.

Comment: I think pdftk.exe is honouring the Owner Password flag, which  adobe reader doesnt. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @mkl- I have password for the file ,i can open it with Adobe reader using input password. It doent ask me for Owner password. But when  i try to  automate in vba using pdftk. i am  observing the error.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to include the VBA which runs this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works if you provide the same value you provide as input password as the owner password?